# Call tableView: cellForRowAtIndex again? Swift - iOS

Tags: ios, swift

I am wondering is there a way to have cellForRowAtIndex delegate method called again in viewDidAppear. I'm not sure if this is even possible, but curious if it can be achieved?

Comment: Call `reloadData` on your table view.

Comment: Hi, will this basically call all the delegated methods again?

Comment: Yes, it sure will. If you want to update only a single cell, you'll have to fetch it from the tableview first and then do your update functions on it.

Comment: Note that your calling `cellForRow...` would accomplish nothing -- the cell would not be reloaded.  It must be called by the table view to have any effect.

Comment: Yeah thats why I did say I wasn't sure if calling `cellForRowAtIndex` was possible in the question. reloadData()` was the method I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Although swift wouldn't prevent you from doing that, you won't probably get the expected results.

I think what you need is just reloading the table, in that case simply:

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

As you may guess, that will reload the entire table, causing each cell to be regenerated via `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Not sure if what you are looking for is [`reloadRowsAtIndexPaths`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:), which is used to reload one or more rows instead of the entire table.

Comment: Ah yes brilliant, once cellForRowAtIndexPath is called again when viewDidAppear then it should work. Thanks!

Comment: One may also use a method (forget the exact name) that reloads just *some* cells.

Comment: @HotLicks: had the same though - just updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reload a specific tableview cell, you can use

```
self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None);
```